# The best way to define an array of tuples in julia

Tags: arrays, julia

In Julia v0.4, the following two works:

```
Array{Tuple{Int, Int}}(10)
```

and

```
 Array(Tuple{Int, Int}, 10)
```

Which is the better way? Is there any reason that one should be preferred to another?

I recognized that a previously working code

```
 Array((Int, Int), 10)
```

no longer works in Julia v0.4. I am afraid that one of the above two currently working code also does not work in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs, `Array(T, dims)` is deprecated, so I would go with the first.

http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/arrays/#Base.Array